# RubyMine 4.5.2 on MacOSX MountainLion keeps asking for SVN credentials

Tags: svn, authentication, osx-mountain-lion, rubymine

Since upgrading to RubyMine 4.5 and MAcOSX MountainLion every time I interact with Subversion I need to re-authenticate myself. It seems that the SVN auth cache is broken, either in RubyMine, MountainLion or the combination of the too. Anyone else experience this? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: Looks like http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85775.

Comment: What worked for me was: Reset Master Password in RubyMine -> Preferences -> Passwords; then "Reset my Default Chain" in Keychain Access -> Preferences. After that RubyMine informed me that the SVN password could only be stored in plaintext on the disk - this dialogue had never come up before, not ideal, but at least now the passwords are saved.